# How to pluralize collections when performing scaffold dbcontext?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I performed a scaffold dbcontext and everything is fine exception the collections aren't pluralized. Is there an argument I can add to the command to fix this?

This is the command I ran:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "my connection string" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Entities -c DbEntities
```

What I want:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm getting:

```
public partial class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is your "order" table named `Order` or `Orders`?

Comment: All tables are singular, so Order.

Comment: You'll need to rename it to Orders.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that? I'm fine with one Order being singular, I just preferred Collections to be pluralized.

Comment: It's based on the table name. It's assumed to be plural, so it the plural becomes "Order" and singular would the singular of that, which of course is still "Order".

Comment: Ok well thank you anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at this plugin?

https://www.bricelam.net/2018/03/02/efcore-pluralization.html

Comment: This is late but I got back to this problem and found this. It works great, thanks!